# How to reference "this" object in java bytecode

Tags: java, bytecode

I am making a class in Java bytecode. I need to know how to reference fields in this object. First I need to know how to reference the "this" object as if I were accessing `this.var1` from class `TestClass`. I know how to access fields in other objects, but not from the same object that I am executing from.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `this` pointer is implicit in every method call, as a hidden first parameter. In all non-static methods, you can push it onto the stack with `aload_0`.

[More details here](http://www.theserverside.com/news/1363881/The-Working-Developers-Guide-to-Java-Bytecode), or as Holger points out, [in the JVM spec itself](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jvms/se7/html/jvms-3.html#jvms-3.6).

Comment: And the official source is the [JVM specification](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jvms/se7/html/jvms-3.html#jvms-3.6): “By convention, an instance method is passed a reference to its instance in local variable 0.”